# Can I filter an array using a boolean array obtained from a compound statement?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of some dimension and I would like to make a slice of this array using a boolean array.
For instance, given my array called 'verts' and I want to make a slice of this array into another array called 'upper' based on some condition. I can do the following:

```
cond_upper = verts[:,2]<L/2
upper = verts[cond_upper]
```

How can I modify the above snippet so that a double condition is satisfied, something like this:

```
cond_upper = verts[:,2]<L/2 and verts[:,2]<40.0
upper = verts[cond_upper]
```

This does not give me the desired result because python wants me to compare them element-wise, however this is not what I want to do.
How can I resolve this?

I add an example to make things clearer:

```
verts = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9],])
cond = verts[:,2]>3 and verts[:,2]<7
upper = verts[cond]
```

Expected result:

```
upper = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],]
```

I hope this makes it somewhat clearer

Comment: Can you update your code with a sample and the expected result please?

Comment: Not sure which array package you are using, but try `&` instead of `and`.

Comment: @corralien I added an edit

Comment: @mozway I get the following error when I use that:  TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: @mozway It works fine, I googled a little bit and I found out I needed to put some brackets. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Your expect results is not a boolean array — so no, things aren't clearer.

Comment: @martineau I do not need the boolean array as my final result. I would just like the final array called 'upper' to contain the filtered elements according to the boolean array obtained from the condition i specified

Comment: The you should [edit] your question and change the title. Also, if you're using numpy, should should mention that, too (and add the tag to your question).

Comment: @martineau is right. I think you use numpy else your operations can't work. I post an equivalent solution with python only.

Comment: question is edited appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the bitwise operator `&` for element comparisons, not `and`.

```
import numpy as np
verts = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9],])
cond = (verts[:,2]>=3) & (verts[:,2]<7)
upper = verts[cond]
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Check your code... If it's not a numpy array, it can't work!

Comment: OP mentioned the input was an array, I added the import for clarity ;)

Comment: Indeed I use a numpy array  and the answer submitted by @mozway works fine. I should have added in the question that I am using a numpy array. I have properly edited the question now

Comment: Missing parenthesis: `cond = (verts[:,2]>3) & (verts[:,2]<7)`

Comment: And the filter don't give the expect output because 3 > 3 is not True. 3 >= 3 is True

Comment: Let me run the real thing (I originally did not plan to post an answer, just did it per OP's request) ;) edit: **fixed** thx @Corralien for your vigilance ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> [row for row in verts if row[2] >= 3 and row[2] < 7]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```